# Как написать запрос по поиску записей с исключенным json-значением и несуществующим json-ключом одновременно?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails

У меня есть таблица `students` с json колонкой с названием `json`. В этой колонке есть разные ключи. Мне нужно вытянуть записи, у которых нет конкретного значения `Fail` в ключе `rating` и одновременно мне нужны записи, где json ключ `rating` не существует. Как это возможно реализовать?

```rb
# Объекты

json: { rating: 'Pass' }
json: { grade: 'A' }
json: { rating: 'Fail' }
```

В общем, мне нужно исключить из результата записи с `rating: 'Fail'` и вернуть все остальные записи, включая те, у которых json-ключ `rating` не существует.

Результат запроса должен быть следующим:

```rb
json: { rating: 'Pass' }
json: { grade: 'A' }
```

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: А что не так с `where("json ->> 'rating' != 'Pass'")`?

Comment: @Василиса А если такого ключа не существует - что будет, а?

Comment: *У меня есть таблица students с json колонкой с названием json.* Бессмысленно описывать... просто выложите CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO с примером данных.

Comment: @Akina должен вернуть 'null', что вполне нас устраивает в рамках задачи

Comment: Сорри, не то значение воткнула в условие -  `where("json ->> 'rating' != 'Fail'")`

Comment: @Василиса И что будет с записью, если условие WHERE для неё даёт NULL? вернёт её запрос или нет?

Comment: @Василиса к сожалению ваш запрос будет пропускать записи, у которых ключ `rating` не существует.

Comment: Ага, поняла. Давно джсоновых полей в базе не попадалось. Счас подумаю, как это можно сделать

Comment: @Василиса Еще таким sql запросом `SELECT * FROM test WHERE val->>'rating' IS DISTINCT FROM 'Fail'` получается добиться желаемого.

Comment: Ну и нормально, это уже можно положить в where. Всё равно придётся условие для where писать на чистом sql, этого точно не избежать. А вот так `where("json ->> 'rating' != 'Fail' OR json ->> 'rating' IS NULL  ")` тоже не работает?

Comment: @Василиса Работает, я счастлив!

Comment: С вашего позволения запилю ответ тогда :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Придётся всё же вспомнить чистый sql

```
Student.where("json ->> 'rating' != 'Fail' OR json ->> 'rating' IS NULL")
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT * FROM test
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM test WHERE val->>'rating' = 'Fail'
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ba33df3cb3903b9a166475af38b51490

Comment: Благодарю, действительно работает! У меня еще такой вопрос - а можно каким-то альтернативным образом достичь этой же цели, то есть переписать запрос не используя оператор EXCEPT? Или это единственное возможное решение? Спасибо

Comment: @AlexanderShmatko Можно. Но зачем? понятное, лаконичное и достаточно производительное решение.

Comment: @Akina это ж рельсы, там хочется взять максимум от актив рекорда и минимум от чистого скуэль

Comment: @Василиса вы правы. Но, честно говоря, я не смог додуматься до решения средствами ORM. Похоже придется писать чистый SQL запрос.

Comment: @Василиса Мне это ни о чём не говорит. Это как функция - передал параметры, получил результат, и не наше дело, что там внутри. А с таким подходом можно договориться до того, что все стандартные библиотеки побоку, и считать всё будем сами... ассемблерными вставками. Автор сам виноват - не надо было приплетать PostgreSQL в теги.